# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to create a .txt file through my app in android studio. SDK version 10, my emulator is galaxy S7 (I am not sure if this matters at all).

I have written the following class and it keeps on giving me file no exception error. I have googled a lot and searched this forum but none of them is working.

Please help.

My Class..

```
public static void StoreData(String input) throws IOException {
    File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    Log.d("hello",Root.getAbsolutePath());
    File Dir = new File(Root.getAbsoluteFile() + "/testfolder");
    if (!Dir.exists()) {
        Log.d("hello","doesn't exists "+Root.getAbsolutePath());
        Dir.mkdir();
    }

    File file = new File(Dir, "Contacts_Google_Sheets.txt");
    FileOutputStream fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fileoutputstream.write(input.getBytes());
    fileoutputstream.close();
    Log.d("hello", "writing complete");
}
```

It keeps on giving following error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/testfolder/Contacts_Google_Sheets.txt (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
W/System.err:     at com.therock.app3_contact_list_googlesheet_public.FileOperations.StoreData(FileOperations.java:55)
W/System.err:     at com.therock.app3_contact_list_googlesheet_public.GetDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetDataAsyncTask.java:64)
W/System.err:     at com.therock.app3_contact_list_googlesheet_public.GetDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetDataAsyncTask.java:33)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/EGL_emulation: tid 3410: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x8fe424c0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
```

Comment: Make sure you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, including [requesting it at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: My android manifest file already has below permissions..<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: and I read runtime permissions were needed for SDK version 23+

Comment: Your Galaxy S7 is very unlikely to be running Android 2.3.3 (API Level 10). It should be running Android 6.0 or higher (API Level 23+).

Comment: `Dir.mkdir();`. Check the return value as it returns false if it cannot create the directory. In that case display a toast to the user telling so. And return. As it makes little sense trying to create a file in a directory that does not exisr.

Answer (score 5):

You have to check the permission from runtime. If you want to just test your code right away, go to device's settings, apps, your_app, then choose permissions from there. Allow the permissions. And you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, including requesting it at runtime. –